# Request to vowpal wabbit daemon hands

Tags: python, sockets, vowpalwabbit

While I was reproducing example in [Daemon example](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Daemon-example) I found that after command `echo " abc-example| a b c" | netcat localhost 26542`  the result printed out and hands until I Ctrl+C.

I tryed to do in python:

```
class VWClient:
    def __init__(self, vwhost, vwport):
        self._host = vwhost
        self._port = vwport

    def request(self, message: str) -> bytes:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.connect((self._host, self._port))
            print('Socket connected to', self._host, 'on port', self._port)

            s.sendall(message.encode() + b'\n')
            response = s.recv(1024)
            return response
```

This happens in python code after I send message and trying to recv. It just hands on line `response = self._socket.recv(1024)`
What I'm doing wrong?